# Anchor programs not working in react native and expo environment [TypeError: b.readUIntLE is not a function (it is undefined)]

Tags: solana-program, anchor-program-idl, react-native, mobile-wallet-adapter

[image]

I'm facing this error when I'm interacting with an onchain program on solana using anchor in expo react native , its the same outcome when I run it with the AnchorCounterProgram example on the tutorials repo
This is the error I get when I try fetching an account const fetchAndUpdateCounter = useCallback(
async (program: Program) => {
try {
const counterAccount = await program.account.counter.fetch(counterPDA);
console.log('counter account', counterAccount.count.toString());
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
},
[counterPDA]
);
[TypeError: b.readUIntLE is not a function (it is undefined)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoke offline and found a temporary fix for this issue.

Workaround is to downgrade your Anchor version (both Anchor CLI and @coral-xyz/anchor in your RN project) to <= v0.28.0.

The root cause of this issue is some polyfill issue with the `buffer` package in React Native. Will report back when I discover the root cause.